# Subject verb agreement with collective nouns

Tags: verbs

In this sentence, which verb is correct?

(Is/Are) staff given discounts on supplies?

Comment: "Are"  with "staff" sounds right, to me.

Comment: "staff" as a group of people is plural, so it's "are staff given given discounts on supplies?"

Answer (score 0):

Either can be used depending on where the speaker is from and how they view "staff."  Most of the textbooks I use are published in Britain and talk about companies and staff using "have" as in "Staff at [X] have been reduced due to lay offs."  Because I am American, I prefer to say "Staff has been reduced."  Extending this, I would say "Is staff responsible..."  I have actually had to use this expression before but when I spoke it I said "Are staff members responsible for classroom supplies?"